# How to correct shape of Keras input into a 3D array

Tags: pandas, numpy, dataframe, keras

I've a Keras model that when I fit fails with this error

```
> kerasInput = Input(shape=(None, 47))
> LSTM(..)(kerasInput)
...
> model.fit(realInput, ...)
ValueError: Error when checking input: expected input_1 to have 3 dimensions, but got array with shape (10842, 1)
```

When looking at my input I found it has a shape of `(10842, 1)` but for each row it's actually a list of list. I can verify with

```
> pd.DataFrame(realInput[0]).shape
(260, 47)
```

How I could correct my input shape?

When trying with keras `Reshape` layer, the creation of the model fails with:

```
Model inputs must come from `keras.layers.Input` (thus holding past layer metadata), they cannot be the output of a previous non-Input layer. Here, a tensor specified as input to your model was not an Input tensor, it was generated by layer reshape_8.
Note that input tensors are instantiated via `tensor = keras.layers.Input(shape)`.
The tensor that caused the issue was: reshape_8/Reshape:0
```

Comment: What model are you using ? Are you using LSTM by any chance ?

Comment: yeah I've an LSTM layer that process the input

Comment: LSTM accepts 3-dimensional input of shape (batch_size, sequence_length, feature_size). What does your input array represent?

Comment: I know that, the thing is I'm transforming a string column into an array of array. As shown above the rows has good shape but then when I pass as input the model fit fails

Comment: My guess is that you have to reshape your data to match the 3-D format before feeding it as an input. Also, for the input_shape, it should be a 2-d vector of (timesteps, number_of_features).

Answer (score 4):

1. You can use numpy.expand_dims method to convert the shape to 3D.

   ```
   import numpy as np

   np.expand_dims(realInput,axis=0)
   ```
2. Reshape layer keras

   https://keras.io/layers/core/#reshape
3. Use the third parameter as 1

   ```
   # Something Similar to this
   X_train = np.reshape(X_train,(X_train.shape[0],X_train.shape[1],1))
   ```

Edit: Added np.reshape method

Refer this repository: https://github.com/NilanshBansal/Stock_Price_Prediction/blob/master/Stock_Price_Prediction_20_days_later_4_LSTM.ipynb

Comment: I updated the post above with the error when using `Reshape`

Comment: I which it solved, I'm trying to use your tips to getting working, I upvoted but will definitely accept once I resolve the issue.

Answer (score 1):

As I said before in the comments. You will need to make sure to reshape your data to match what LSTM expects to receive and also make sure the input_shape is correctly set.

I found this post quite helpful when I struggled with inputting to an LSTM layer. I hope it helps you too : [Reshape input for LSTM](https://machinelearningmastery.com/reshape-input-data-long-short-term-memory-networks-keras/)